# Does Fineuploader support Server-Side Encryption with Customer-Provided Encryption Keys

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

We recently started using Fineuploader and got it working with server side encryption. But we now want to use "Server-Side Encryption with Customer-Provided Encryption Keys" [documentation can be found here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html). I searched the API and checked the blog and couldn't find anything about it.

Does Fineuploader support this?
If it does how do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set `x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-algorithm`, `x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key`, and `x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key-MD5` using the [`request.params`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-s3.html#request.params) option, and [`setParams()`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setParams) method.

When you add these headers, make sure to leave off the `x-amz-` prefix as Fine Uploader will add this for you.

`request.params = {
   "server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm": "foo",
   "server-side​-encryption​-customer-key": "bar",
   "server-side​-encryption​-customer-key-MD5": "baz",
}`

Comment: Problem with that is that it adds 'x-amz-meta-' to the name and not 'z-amz-' if you add it to the `request.params`. So I actually updated the code so when I add anything to `request.params` that starts with 'x-amz-' it doesn't add 'x-amz-meta-' to the header.

Comment: That isn't the correct fix for this issue.  All custom params must be prefixed with x-amz-meta.  We will need to provide a way for integrators to specify additional s3 defined headers as well though.

Comment: Would you like me to send my code change to you to see if you would like to us it?